# Doxygen: Generate makefiles for Linux from Windows

Tags: makefile, doxygen, gnu-make

I'm fixing some problems in an already existing project. In this project the documentation is generated using Doxygen. Pdf documentation is needed.

The project has to run on Windows. We are using a suite from DDC-I (for safety critical software) that has is own command prompt. This command prompt "emulates" (like cygwin) some Unix commands and tools, like "make" and here is the problem.

When I generate the documentation Doxygen creates some Makefiles and since I'm on Windows this makefiles contain the command "del", but when I call "make clean" from my command prompt I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: del: command not found make: *** [clean] Error 12
```

This happen because the command prompt uses Unix-like make and aspect to see the "rm" command instead of the "del" command.
I've tried different solutions but the easiest would be to generate makefiles for Linux even if I'm on windows. 
Is it possible?

Thank you in advance!

Here is the system:
Doxygen 1.7.4
Windows XP
GNU Make 3.81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to configure this, but since version 1.8.0 doxygen writes a make.bat (using del) which you can use in a pure Windows environment and a Makefile (using rm) which you can use in a Cygwin like environment.

Comment: Thank you, updating to the latest version worked like a charm! I cannot give you +1 since my reputation is not high enough, I hope someone else will do it!